# Log4j 2.8 cannot load custom converters in OSGi environment

Tags: java, plugins, osgi, converters, log4j2

I'm currently switching to log4j2 and I'm working in OSGi environment. There's been couple of issues with OSGi in log4j 2.7 branch which encouraged me to grab 2.8 as the final library.
The thing is I have couple of custom PatternConverters implemented in my project and I can't manage to have them loaded and recognized

```
DEBUG Initializing configuration XmlConfiguration[location=C:\Program Files\...\etc\log4j2.xml]
.
.
DEBUG Took 0,001043 seconds to load 0 plugins from package common.audit.sink.impl.log4j2.converter
```

although there's at least 10 of them. This later results in errors like:

```
DEBUG Building Plugin[name=layout, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout].
DEBUG PatternLayout$Builder(pattern="%ED;...
ERROR Unrecognized format specifier [ED]
ERROR Unrecognized conversion specifier [ED] starting at position 3 in conversion pattern.
```

I have pretty much everything set up as necessary (it worked with 2.7 anyways).
The plugin implementation annotated and both *newInstance*, *format* methods implemented according to [this guide](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/extending.html#PatternConverters)

The packages declaration in log4j2.xml:

```
<Configuration status="trace" name="Systemtest_Server" packages="common.audit.sink.impl.log4j2.converter">
```

The plugins metadata is generated and present in *.jar bundle containing plugins

```
META-INF\org\apache\logging\log4j\core\config\plugins\Log4j2Plugins.dat
```

The log4j-core-2.8.jar bundle is activated together with log4j-api-2.8.jar at the startup of Equinox container. The configuration file is pointed by system property and works (obviously from the debug message I receive).

However, I found [this issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1753) reported on log4j Jira, which is kind of my problem as I was facing the same exception until I modified *log4j-api-2.8.jar* to make it import *org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util* package so my server would start normally. There are some comments suggesting that this might lead to non-extensibility of log4j2 in OSGi.

So is there some way how to overcome this issue (quick fix is enough)?  Alternatively, is there something that I might be forgetting to configure here?

Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I'm gonna answer this for myself and maybe it will help somebody too. I did a lot of playing around and the fault was in OSGi with which I'm not so familiar, to be honest.

I found out in the end that you have to ensure these things:

- The bundle has to be activated in OSGi container. Inactive bundles are not scanned for plugins. The fact that you mark bundle for activation in your configuration doesn't necessarily mean it will actually happen. E.g., some fault in my bundle's manifest prevent this from happening. So to be sure I build bundle with
  `Export-Package: common.audit.sink.impl.log4j2.*`
  `Import-Package: *`
- At least one of following has to hold to get your plugins loaded:

  - Your bundle with custom plugins is a fragment of log4j-core by stating this in its manifest:
    `Fragment-Host: org.apache.logging.log4j.core`
    Probably the right approach.
  - Your bundle is activated with the same priority as log4j bundles (not only API but also Core needs to be active to enable plugin-search)

Of course the configuration mentioned in my question is needed as well. After this I got no errors and saw a trace like this:

```
DEBUG Oracle Nashorn Version: 1.8.0_102, Language: ECMAScript, Threading: Not Thread Safe, Compile: true, Names: {nashorn, Nashorn, js, JS, JavaScript, javascript, ECMAScript, ecmascript}
DEBUG Took 0,008133 seconds to load 16 plugins from package common.audit.sink.impl.log4j2.converter
DEBUG PluginManager 'Core' found 112 plugins
DEBUG PluginManager 'Level' found 0 plugins
...
DEBUG Building Plugin[name=layout, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout].
DEBUG PatternLayout$Builder(pattern="%ED;%EU;%EL;...
DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appender, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileAppender].
```